# Maintaining a shapes DB for indexed text highlight on images

Tags: android, android-canvas, shapes

I need guidance in designing a solution for my use case.
That is, we have a book [images], we want to highlight sentences by maintaining a database by manually drawing shapes on each sentence and saving its coordinates and bounds in the database.
Now is there a tool to do that quickly? like draw rectangles on one image and with a click export them into DB?
Below is the sample Model I am to use for this purpose...

```
      public SentenceHighlight(int line, int position, int minX, int minY, int maxX, int maxY) {
    this(line, position, new RectF(minX, minY, maxX, maxY));
  }

  public SentenceHighlight(int line, int position, RectF bounds) {
    this.line = line;
    this.position = position;
    this.bounds = bounds;
  }
```

Comment: I am a bit unclear on your use case. Is it always going to be a Rect? or can the user draw any shape on screen and you want to store that as well?

Comment: Yes, It will always be React. I want to save them indexed so I can maintain order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so my guess is that you have Multiple sentences, and you use `Rect` shape to highlight them. Again by highlight, I assume you are using `Canvas.drawRect(Rect)`.

If this is the case, then you could save your configuration in a Json format. Basically, you would have a `Map<Sentence, Rect>`. You already have your model , so you could use the same.

There aren't any tools for you to do this automatically. But it should be easy to build anyway. All you have to do is keep adding your Highlights to the `Map` and then once it's ready, you could just use Moshi or GSON and get a Json out of it and save that to DB.

Comment: Yes thats good idea, I have already done something similar. I was hoping, if there is a way.

Comment: I have read some threads some people are suggesting using matlab and exporting json. But I am completely unaware of that tools usage.

Comment: I don't think you need all this, given that the model you are trying to save is very simple. You could express the Rect using its Bounds (which is just 4 integers). So the simplest solution here is to get the Map, and convert that to a Json and save that. You could fetch it back, and draw the Rect again. If it's a book, you could have One json per page, so that you can parse and read quickly.